# How to get token using javascript in Django Rest Framework TokenAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I followed the doc here [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) and already create token for every user.but I don't how to get token in javascript? For example, I wannt post a comment, using ajax like

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/comment/",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data:  {"reply_id": "1", csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", and token here?},
});
```

But how can I get current user's token? cookies has set **http-only** and I can't access it. Maybe I should sent another ajax to get the token by using username(which I display on my website) to search the database first?

Any help is welcome, Thanks.

EDIT: Should I use localStorage instead?

Comment: Do you also allow `SessionAuthentication` ? If so, then you don't really need to pass the token at all..

Comment: @mariodev, I'm not sure it's good to use SessionAuthentication in web and  TokenAuthentication in mobile app?

Comment: It's a standard practice to follow. `SessionAuthentication` is best fitted for web apps where `TokenAuthentication` is used for mobile. If you set both in DRF's settings, it will handle both web and mobile auth flow.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to retrieve the auth token by logging in using the users credentials. You then have an auth token which you can store in your localStorage for example.

The JS code for logging in looks roughly like this;

```
var credentials = {
  username: "admin",
  password: "abc123"
};

$.post("http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/", credentials, function(auth) {
    console.log("Logged in, auth token: ", auth.token);
}
```

Comment: Is store in localStorage is a better way? I had read a article here https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/

Comment: I used localStorage as an example, as I thought the question was about getting the actual token instead of storing it.

Stormpath indeed prefers storing your **Json Web Tokens(JWT)** secure cookes over localStorage, although JWT's are quite secure by nature(that's why JWT.io doesn't prefer a storage method).
However, you are using ordinary auth tokens, if you wish to use JWT's, you will need to use the http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/ app instead.
If you wish to remain using the ordinary auth tokens, you can consider timing them out(regenerating them) to increase security.